# C#: Dateformat in C# for Inserting to sql server

Tags: c#

I have a textbox with date format `dd/MM/yyyy` that I want to convert to the format `yyyy-MM-dd` to insert it into a database.

I tried

```
Convert.DateTime/DateTime.ParseExact
```

but it always give me the system's default date format.

I don't know any other method to convert it in C#...

Comment: convert to `DateTime`, then call ToString using the appropriate [date format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't be converting it to a string *at all* to insert it into your database. (I'm surprised at all the other answers which are recommending this approach.)

Instead, you should be using parameterized SQL, and set the value of the parameter to the `DateTime` value you've got. You should be using parameterized SQL *anyway* to avoid SQL injection attacks, and to keep your code and data separate. The fact that it avoids unnecessary string conversions (each of which is a potential pain point) is yet another benefit.

This part of your question suggests you've got a fundamental misconception:

> I used Convert.DateTime/DateTime.ParseExact it always give me system date format.

Those methods will give you a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format. When you call `ToString` you just get the default format for the current culture, but that's *not* part of the value. It's like with numbers - 16 and 0x10 are the same number, and the `int` doesn't "know" whether it's in decimal or hex; it's a meaningless concept.

All of this goes beyond your immediate problem, towards trying to keep your code base clean in terms of types. You should keep data in its most appropriate form for as much of the time as you *possibly* can, and make sure you understand exactly what that data means at all points. Conversions to other types (such as strings) for communication should be done only at API/system boundaries, and avoided even there if possible (e.g. using parameterized SQL as in this case).

Answer (score 3):

**There are many methods but none so useful and logical than using Parametrized SQL.** Here's [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements)! For more information on Parametrized SQL statements, Visit this [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) page!

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no need to change it. This is just the display format, but the 'DateTime' object inside stays the same. Depending on how you want to insert, you can just use:

```
string dateValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And insert this in your query string.

**EDIT**

But as Jon Skeet commented, building your query string manually like this should never be done. A cleaner approach like parameterized SQL or utilizing NHibernate should be your first concern.

Comment: No, *don't* insert values into query strings at all. Use parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: You are right, he shouldn't actually do this. I mostly use NHibernate and don't have this issue at all. But from his question I was guessing, that he is building his query string.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure he is. But the right approach isn't to tell him how to keep doing the wrong thing - it's to tell him what he should be doing instead.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works!

DateTime variable= Convert.ToDateTime(*your date*);

Answer (score -1):

You can format it like this:

```
string sDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTextBox.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**Edit**

There are many ways to skin a cat when it comes to preparing information for entry into a database. My solution here answers the OP directly, however I very much acknowledge that there are better ways to do this.

I'd suggest reading through Jon Skeet's post on this page as well, as he raises some extremely valid points regarding the approach of the OP.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't - you should use parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a request as to whether or not he *should* do this, it was simply asked whether it was possible, and how it could be achieved, thus I've responded to the OP's question as requested.

Comment: Personally I think that's a terrible attitude, and one which does nothing to improve industry standards. If you know the OP's current approach is poor and that there are better alternatives, why would you *not* say so?

Comment: Jon, this code could be for some experimental app, for a throw away in house project that just has to do one thing, for a project where time to market is more important and valuable to the OP and their clients. Did you consider this before getting on your high horse, or did you just assume that everyone only develops enterprise level applications?

Comment: I assumed that everyone would at least want to *know* if they're doing something bad. A "project where time to market is important" isn't the same as a "project where SQL injection doesn't matter". Parameterized SQL is easy and has many benefits. I would use it in throw-away projects, experimental apps, personal projects etc. The idea that writing good code is only applicable for "enterprise level applications" is scary.

Comment: I see that, however that's an assumption, and we all know where they get us in software. It's easy to assume that everyone should be writing code at your level, or that everyone is developing solutions that are as involved or as complex as ones that perhaps you work on, but the simple fact is that this is not the case.

Comment: Whereas you appear to have made the opposite assumption - that the OP wouldn't even want to have the information about what they should be doing. I wouldn't have bothered commenting if your answer included the preferred alternative - but no, it's *just* the formatting bit. I believe my approach is a much more constructive one in the long term. I believe most people actually want to improve their skills. Do you disagree?

Comment: I haven't made any assumption at all, I've simply answered the OP's post *as they requested* - repeat: *no* assumptions were made! Without limiting that statement though, I agree with everything you've said in your answer posted above, hopefully the OP has the knowledge he needs from your post to implement his solution in that fashion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15749/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-rastus7)